# Put if absent to map in scala

Tags: scala, collections

I have the following map:

```
val m: mutable.Map[String, Long] = mutable.Map()
```

and I want to just put some value into it if it's not present. If it is present in turn I want to perform some computations:

Currently I do it in the following way:

```
val key: String = //...
val value: Long = //...
m(key) = m.getOrElse(key, 0L) + value
```

But this feels a bit verbose to me (In Java we have `putIfAbsent` method). Is there a shorter way to do so in Scala?

Comment: The title and the content of the question point to a typical XY-problem. While you were trying to solve the actual question, you've found out that you don't need what you are asking for in the title... So, maybe you should update the title to "Update default value if a value is absent in a map (in Scala)", or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For [mutable maps](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html) you can either override the `default` method, or add a default computation with `withDefault`, so that it automatically computes all the missing values on first access:

```
val m = new HashMap[String, Int].withDefault(k => 0)
```

Then you can update the values like this:

```
m("foo") += 5
m("bar") += 7
m("foo") += 37

println(m) // Map(foo -> 42, bar -> 7)
```

Comment: So no something like `putIfAbsent`...?

Comment: `withDefault` is something like an auto-triggered `putIfAbsent`. It is invoked automatically every time a new key is accessed.

Comment: @St.Antario If you really want *exactly* the functionality of `putIfAbsent`, you can indeed use `getOrElseUpdate`, and then ignore the returned value. So, in a way, Yuval Itzchakov literally answers the part of your question in parentheses about the analogon for a Java method. I just don't see how it is supposed to help with your actual question of how to make the "get and update" shorter. If you use `getOrElseUpdate` instead of `getOrElse`, your code becomes longer and a tiny bit less performant (because of one additional write). It's not Java. Write what works in Scala.

Comment: Still don't understand how `getOrElseUpdate` helps... It sets the new value without taking the previous one into account. https://ideone.com/SLbuex

Comment: 'm(key) = m.getOrElseUpdate(key, 0L) + value` would work. But it's longer than your original code, and it writes the zero unnecessarily, because it gets immediately overridden anyway.

Comment: Understood. Anyway using `withDefaultValue` seems more pretty to me.

Comment: @St.Antario : `withDefaultValue` would also be faster in this case. There is no analogon in Java, because the imperative do-it-right-now `putDefaultValueToAllAbsentKeys` would have to put a `0` for infinitely many keys, which obviously cannot work.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for [`mutable.Map.getOrElseUpdate`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#getOrElseUpdate(key:K,op:=%3EV):V):

```
m.getOrElseUpdate(key, value)
```

Comment: While this is certainly a very handy method, I don't see how it would help in this particular use case. Wouldn't it just make the assignment exactly 6 characters longer, and require one additional `put(0)` once for every key?

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work as I expected. [demo](https://ideone.com/SLbuex). I expected `key -> 50L`, but `key -> 20L` was.